# Variable 'xxx' is used before being assigned

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this piece of code

```
  let hostel : HostelType;

              hostels.forEach( (r) => {
                  const i =  r.identifier.findIndex((_identifier: any) => _identifier.id === '433456');
                  hostel = hostels[i];
              });

              hostel.serviceLevel.value = 'P';
```

but I have a compilation error:

```
 Variable 'hostel' is used before being assigned.
```

Comment: you variable hostel doesnot hold any value

Comment: You declared `hostel` as type `HostelType` but you don't initialize it. So if the forEach has no value then `hostel = hostels[i]` won't be done. So you then try to accesss `serviceLevel` of an empty object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be sure that there is an instance assigned:

```
let hostel : HostelType;

hostels.forEach( (r) => {
  const i =  r.identifier.findIndex((_identifier: any) => _identifier.id === '433456');

  if (i === -1 || !hostels[i]) {
    throw new Exception('There is no hostel');
  }

  hostel = hostels[i];
});

hostel.serviceLevel.value = 'P';
```

Ideally the code should be something like that:

```
const hostel = hostels.find(x => x.identifier === '433456');
```

It's not clear why `identifier` is an array and how it's related to the index in the `hostels` array.

Answer (score 0):

You are using it before being initialized.

You need to initialize it before the loop with something like `hostel = new HostelType();`

Answer (score 0):

You either need to initialize `hostel` before using it in your `hostel.serviceLevel.value = 'P';` statement,
or check if it is indeed defined :

```
if (typeof hostel !== 'undefined') {
    hostel.serviceLevel.value = 'P';
}
```

---

The `hostel` variable may be undefined :

- if `hostels` is empty (the code inside the callback will never be called),
- if the last element in `hostels` contains an identifier whose `id` field matches `433456` (`i` will be `-1` on the last iteration)